# Raspberry Pi 4 can't connect to BLE device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi4

Device : RPI4
System : Ubuntu 22.04
Bluez version : 5.64

I am trying to connect a BLE device through bluetoothctl but i am getting an error called Le connection abort by local. Does anyone know about that issue.

I have tried to change bluez version but it did not work.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276266/how-to-edit-a-previously-asked-stack-exchange-question) your question to add some debug information. Have you been able to connect with a general BLE exploration tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile)? Does the device you are connecting to need to be paired first?